# How to restart a loop processing multiple files in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I have multiple files to be processed and compressed into .tar.gz. I have to load them in a RAMDISK in order to have a faster way to process multiple files (in the order of millions). There are so many files that I need a way to restart my script in case it can't be done in less than 48 hours.

The script starts like this:

```
cd ${RAMDISK} && tar xfz file.tar.gz
for FILE in ${RAMDISK}/file/*; do
...
done
```

I was thinking of using the file number and adding something like this to the script:

```
cd ${RAMDISK} && tar xfz file.tar.gz

for FILE in ${RAMDISK}/file/*; do
if {! -f next.no}; then    
...
let $fileno=$fileno+1
echo $fileno > next.no
else
...
let $fileno=$fileno+1
echo fileno > next.no
done
```

I don't know how to use the file number to add it in script and if there is a better way to restart the loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Btw, take a look at GNU tar's option `-C`.

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to do? Do you want to stop processing the files in the loop if you couldn't finish processing them all in less than 48 hours?

Comment: You shouldn't use the fileno solution, perhaps try the solution of @Cyrus. For other problems some feedback: Counting with `fileno=0; (( fileno ++ ))`.
Use curly braces around yoyr variables `${fileno}` and use double quotes in an echo `echo "${fileno}" > next.no`. Use if statement with `if [ ! -f next.no ]; do`. I think you wanted to fill fileno with the content of next.no and make it 0 when the file dowsn't exist.

Comment: So it this code will work better ? FICHIER_TRACE=${SCRATCH}/trace.txt
for FILE in ${RAMDISK}/file/*; do
  RET=$( fgrep ${FILE} ${FICHIER_TRACE} 2>/dev/null 1>&2 )
  if [ $RET -eq 0 ]; then continue; fi

  ... loop ...

  echo ${FILE} >> ${FICHIER_TRACE}
done